Occasions when `runUntilDate` is invoked after `configure` in Salesforce SDK for iOS Objective-C?
In iOS Objective-C, when using the Salesforce SDK, there are cases where the runUntilDate function is called after the configure function. Can someone explain in what scenarios this occurs?
I am using MarketingCloudSDK 7.4.x version.

